# How to use tri-state buffers to make AND and OR logic gates? I can use an inverter

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, homework, tri-state

It's for an assignment where I have to make AND/OR gates using tri-state buffers and NOT gates. Is there any way I can do that without using any other gates?

Comment: Hint: you can connect the actual input of a tri-state buffer to fixed 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll just provide a hint:

- Do you know how to make a multiplexer using two tristate buffers and an inverter?
- Do you know how to implement arbitrary logic using muxes?